# Anonymizing figures in presentation for online use

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to publish some presentation slides of mine online. They contain group and collaborator pictures, which I would like to anonymize by blurring them to be unrecognizable and printing "Anonymized for online use" over them.

I usually include my figures inside tikz nodes using `\includegraphics`. Is there an easy option to introduce the blurring for anonymization? I found [Partial or entire Image Blurring in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295100/partial-or-entire-image-blurring-in-tikz) , but I figure that this is not a good option, since the original could easily be reconstructed. So its not very anonymized really.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that this is possible with the means of LaTeX. Make a copy of each image and blur it in Photoshop, Gimp, etc. This way you can be pretty sure that the content is really blurred.

If you only want to partially blur the images there is no way around manual editing, if you want the whole image blurred you could use e.g. imagemagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_args) to create the blurred images in a batch.

Using LaTeX's `\graphicspath` (see [How to use \graphicspath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath)) you could then easily switch between the blurred and non-blurred versions of the images.

Comment: That seems logical. Is there maybe a way to interface latex with such external tools on this?

Comment: I adjusted my answer, I'd create a batch job to blur all images using imagemagick.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful +1. While a negative answer is fine, in hope for a positive answer I am still hesitant to accept.

Comment: Imagine the blurring would be possible by Adobes Javascript Stack: a) the image would have to be included in the PDF container in its original form and b) what would PDF viewers show that do not support JavaScript. The only way to make it safe is IMHO to blur the images before they are processed by LaTeX.