Tikz: Transform an image to change perspective
In Gimp/Krita/… you can apply a "perspective" transformation on an image by setting a different position for each corner, like:

Is it possible to do that in TikZ? I tried \pgftransformcm but it seems to apply to points but not to images (unsurprisingly).

You could use other (scripting-)languages, like here SAGE is included to get some image blur: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390470/245790 . Look also for tags like python and other tools which do that kind of graphics transformation. Afaik, Tikz won't be able to do what you want (vector- vs. pixel-orientation).

@MS-SPO ok too bad, thanks! Guess I could use my library robust-externalize for this ^^
